# Token got by Firebase is showing as invalid when sending notifications

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get the FCM token using the following method

```
refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
```

I forward this token to the backend, but when the backend sends notifications or create a new topic, the error comes up telling the instance id is invalid or the token is not registered.

It works completely fine for some tokens and for some tokens only it throws a error.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: same thing here. Did you ever found a solution?